# Nodes only go one direction instead of back and forth when animating

Tags: animation, javafx

Learning how to use javafx and I am having problems with my nodes or "targets" bouncing from edge to edge. After the first trip across the pane they stop. This code that I have so far...

```
public class game extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

target1 target1 = new target1();
target2 target2 = new target2();
shooter shooter = new shooter();
Button fireButton = new Button("Fire!");
Pane pane = new Pane();

/**
 * 
 * @param primaryStage 
 */
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setTitle("GAME");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    pane.getChildren().add(fireButton);
    fireButton.setLayoutX(700);
    fireButton.setLayoutY(500);
    pane.getChildren().add(shooter);
    shooter.setX(380);
    shooter.setY(540);
    shooter.setWidth(40);
    shooter.setHeight(20);
    shooter.setArcWidth(20);
    shooter.setArcHeight(20);


    pane.getChildren().add(target1);
    target1.setX(0);
    target1.setY(250);
    target1.setWidth(30);
    target1.setHeight(20);
    target1.setArcWidth(20);
    target1.setArcHeight(20);

    pane.getChildren().add(target2);
    target2.setX(0);
    target2.setY(150);
    target2.setWidth(15);
    target2.setHeight(10);
    target2.setArcWidth(20);
    target2.setArcHeight(20);

    primaryStage.show();
    ShooterButtonPressHandler shooterButton = new ShooterButtonPressHandler();
    fireButton.setOnAction(shooterButton);

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), this);
    Timeline animation = new Timeline(keyFrame);
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play();


}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if (target1.isColliding(pane) ) {
        target1.processCollision();
    }
    target1.animate(pane);
    if (target2.isColliding(pane) ) {
        target2.processCollision();
    }
    target2.animate(pane);

}
/**
 * 
 */
public class ShooterButtonPressHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (target1.getX() >= 370 && target1.getX()<= 400){
            System.out.println("hit");
        }
        if (target2.getX() >= 370 && target2.getX()<= 400){
            System.out.println("hit");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("miss");
        }        
    }                
}
```

this is a class for target 1... target 2 is the exact same.

```
public class target1 extends Rectangle{
int velocity = 1;


public void animate (Pane pane) {
    Double x = this.getX();
    x = velocity + x;
    setX(x);
} // end method animate

public Boolean isColliding (Pane pane) {
    Double side = pane.getWidth();
    Boolean collision = (this.getX() + this.getWidth() >= side);
    if (collision) {
        this.setX(side);
    }
    return collision;
} // end method isColliding

public void processCollision () {
if(velocity == 1){
    this.velocity = -1;
}
else{
    this.velocity = 1;
}
} // end method processCollision
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

The problem you are facing is because of the statement

```
this.setX(side);
```

Lets us consider a scenario where your target reaches the boundary. At this stage, for target1 :

```
X = 790
width = 30
side = 800

X + width = 790 + 30 = 820, which is greater than 800
```

So,

```
collision = true
X = side = 800
```

Now we have,

```
X = 800
width = 30
side = 800

X + width = 800 + 30 = 830, which is greater than 800
```

Again, we have `collision = true` and this goes on forever.

**Solution**

You can set your **X** to a value which is less than `side+width`. There are various ways to achieve this, one of which is

`this.setX(this.getX() - this.getWidth());`

But, this will destroy the sync between the two targets, since their width are unequal. *Finding a better solution is left to the reader*

There is one more issue which I would like to point out, the collision takes care of the collision on the right end and not the left end. To take care of both the ends, you can edit the code as

```
public Boolean isColliding(Pane pane) {
    Double side = pane.getWidth();
    Boolean collision = false;
    if(this.getX() + this.getWidth() >= side) {
        this.setX(this.getX() - this.getWidth());
        collision = true;
    } else if (this.getX() - this.getWidth() <= 0) {
        this.setX(this.getX() + this.getWidth());
        collision = true;
    }
    return collision;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I always overlook details like that when I am coding. The habit is so hard to break but must happen because the more I code the more in love I become lol.